# Blood Dripping Down Screen Effect

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, javascript

I was wondering if anyone had a tutorial or an idea of how to create a dripping effect similar to that of the famous blood drip. In this case, I was curious as to how I could change the color, instead of red, maybe to purple and also keep the background transparent so that I could overlay it on anything.

I'm looking into using this effect on a webpage so that on the click of a button, the effect will happen and essentially cover everything on the page. Maybe, for some cool additions, have the mouse slow down because of the "viscosity" of this liquid and maybe even "erase" the liquid with the mouse pointer once its covered the whole page.

I have Adobe Premiere and After Effects at my disposal. Do I require any other tools?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what is the famous blood drip. But based on your requirements of changing the viscosity I would use a 3D software with liquid simulator. More specifically Blender. https://www.blender.org/

You can change the viscocity, speed, angle, ammount, color, material, framerate, render style... Whatever you need.

https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+fluid+simulation

Regarding the interaction, you need to program that in JavaScript. But Im sure it is quite complicated and out of the realm of graphic design.
An example https://www.escapemotions.com/experiments.php

But you probably can just simulate it using a JavaScript trigger, like Waypoints. http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

An example of a clever animation triggered by events, more specifically the scrolling of the page: http://www.flatvsrealism.com/

Comment: This a great answer, thanks for all of this info. I'm going to look into it and let you know about my progress. Also, on a side note, my name is Rafael haha